# SQL server: IF EXISTS insert x into table A, else insert y into table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting error of "#DateRange already in the database". What I want is, if there is data in #daterange2, then do the union, else only select from #DateRange1. But the destination table would both be in #DateRange table.
Here is my code:

```
IF exists  (SELECT * FROM #DateRange2)
    SELECT * INTO #DateRange
    FROM
    (SELECT * FROM
        #DateRange1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM
        #DateRange2
    ) a
ELSE
    SELECT * INTO #DateRange
    FROM
        #DateRange1
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh, why bother with the conditional logic at all?  Just do:

```
SELECT *
INTO #DateRange
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM #DateRange1
      UNION
      SELECT *
      FROM #DateRange2
     ) a;
```

If there are no rows in the second table, then none get inserted.

Also, check whether you really need `UNION`.  In general, `UNION ALL` is preferred -- unless you really want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: because if #daterange2 not exist, the union will not work

Comment: @JaneZeng . . . Neither will your `if` statement.